# If a model is already processed after uploading to files on ACC, can I skip submitting a translation job?

Tags: autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I have an IFC uploaded onto an ACC project's Files module (i.e. stored in a folder).

I've gotten the URN of the OSS storage object, which looks like this: `urn:adsk.objects:os.object:wip.dm.prod/8e9936f0-dbec-4b70-b6b2-5ce385ff4225.ifc`

It has finished uploading and processing. This means that if I click on it in the Files module, it opens up the 3D model viewer.

However if I check [https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/{urn}/manifest](https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/%7Burn%7D/manifest) it seems as though no manifest is available. This means that if I want to have my own 3D model viewer using the Autodesk viewer, I need to submit my own translation job to SVF2 at https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/job and wait for the job to finish (i.e. check the manifest progress) and only then it'll show up in my own viewer.

Am I misunderstanding the process? It seems unintuitive that I can already view the model online on BIM360/ACC yet when I want to show it on my own viewer I need to submit a translation job.

https://aps.autodesk.com/estimator also suggests that if the model is already on BIM360 it shouldn't cost any tokens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick answer is Yes, there is no need to translate the model again, the model should be automatically translated as long as you upload to ACC Docs.

I just tried my side, when an IFC file is uploaded to ACC Docs, you should be able get the URN of **derivatives.data.id** as shown in the picture, this is the base64 encoded of the file version id, could you please check if you are using the right URN?  [image]

Comment: That can't be the base64 encoded version of the file version Id, because it contains the "_" character so it is invalid base64.

Comment: Oh whoops! Thanks so much! That was it! I didn't realise that that's not a standard base64 encoding, it's a urlsafe base64 encoding (i.e. _ becomes / and - becomes +). After converting it back to standard base64, it works as expected :)